# Excel Online / Office 365 connection with Tableau Desktop

Tags: sharepoint, onedrive

I've tried to connect with Tableau Desktop using Web Data Connector to a an Excel file on OneDrive / Excel Online / Office 365. Even if this seems to be possible with  Google Spreadsheets http://community.tableau.com/groups/dev-community/blog/2015/04/04/google-spreadsheet-with-tableau-web-data-connector, I can't seem to make it work with Excel Online. Using the Web Data Connector I can get to the online spreadsheet but it won't do the data connection... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to any Excel file that is stored in SharePoint or Office 365 / OneDrive for Business via OData as shown here:

http://www.layer2solutions.com/en/solutions/Pages/excel-services-odata-data-integration-synchronization.aspx

You can process the returning XML by yourself, or using the tool.